# How to inject additional service to the ExceptionListener?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5, symfony-security

I want to override the `setTargetPath` from the default *ExceptionListener* ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/target_path.html)). But I need additional service to handle this.

In my opinion there is only the way to override the service definition, copy it to my service definitions and create an own constructor, but I don't like this approach.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What kind of targetPath do you want to override? The default ExceptionListener don't have any setTargetPath method

Comment: This one https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php, that is the default one from the security component. I don't know why you say there is none containing target path.

Comment: Yes, now i see, but that exception listener is called up on authentication exception, not the base symfony default

Comment: Uhm ... I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for answer, if you are using form_login type, you can set it to a constant route where the redirect after login should happen. [Config](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)

You should set these 2 keys:

```
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path:            /route_name_for_redirect
```

Or option B, you use a success handler service, where you simply returns a RedirectResponse

Comment: The success handler approach is nice, I was only looking to overwrite the setter of target path.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the response of the success handler ;)

Comment: I am not sure about it, but yes it would be a possible way. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found another approach using a compiler pass, following steps are necessary:

1. Create your own class extending *ExceptionListener* and add for your dependencies a method
2. Create a compiler pass containing something like the following:

   ```
   class WebCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
   {

       public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
       {
           $definition = $container->getDefinition('security.exception_listener');
           $definition->addMethodCall('yourmethod', [ new Reference('your dependency') ]);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register your compiler pass
4. Overwrite the exception listener class parameter:

   ```
   security.exception_listener.class: AcmeBundle\EventListener\SecurityExceptionListener
   ```